# Should twisted wire joints to 5 kW water heater be soldered?

Tags: electrical, safety

Say I'm connecting a water heater (~5kW) to the mains and I **need** to make a joint, not just replace the cable with a longer one.

Considering the high power consumption, would soldering the joint help in any way?

How the joint is made: 2cm of each wire are twisted together and then compressed with pliers.

Comment: Recall that voltage drop in a resistor is Ohms * Amps. Lets say you're playing with 20 Amps and have a joint resistance of 0.5 ohms. You're getting a 10v drop there. Dropping 10v at 20amps? That'd be 200 watts. Lets assume 0.1 ohms - 2v drop - 20 watts.

Comment: You should ask this in Home Improvement (DIY), there are people there that know the electrical code. Tell them where you are located. I don't think that soldering is allowed in house wiring at all.

Comment: If compression with pliers does not make a gas tight seal, humidity can create corrosion. If the wire cannot move solder can reduce this somewhat but is not better than a wire nut . Contact resistance should be in milliohms

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: Soldering connections in the electrical mains wiring in buildings has been out of favor for decades already. It's too easy to make a joint which 'looks ok' on the surface, but which either fails over time or even immediately because it's sub-standard underneath. The potential for bad joints causing a fire is very high - to ensure safety you must use a method of making connections in mains wiring that is recognized as safe & appropriate for wherever you are in the world.

Comment: 5kW would likely be 20 to 25 amps. Not really a level to raise concern.

Answer (score 3):

### I'd use a lever-lock style of wire connector

Given that your profile says you're in Germany, you should have no trouble getting lever-lock style wire connectors (Wago calls these a Lever-Nut™) and matching carrier boxes for them.  These are approved for splicing basically worldwide, and provide a far more foolproof splice than just about any other device I've heard of.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing that this question comes from the electronics stack, from a presumed electronics person.

I have a question for you... **if solder is such a great conductor, why don't they make wires out of it?**  Heh... it's not.  It's rubbish as a conductor. Go look up its actual conductivity.  Solder is selected because of its other traits - melting point, flow, willingness to stick to copper, ability to work with flux, etc. (and in the case of RoHS solder, lack of lead, which heavily compromises workability).

AC mains power is not anything like electronics.  With electronics, a dab of solder is plenty for the conductivity of the small currents involved.  High-current splices melt all the time, but nobody *tracks* those failures because they don't cause house fires or require large insurance payouts.  So there's no data-driven hard science about failures and no central body telling you how to make splices safe.  Whereas in AC mains, all that exists, and produces the *electrical codes*.

Wiring AC Mains electrical is a professional craft all its own. Obviously they don't spend a lot of time with Thevenin's Theorem.  What they do is artfully follow a *rather thick book* of standards and practices for electrical wiring.  There's *a little* circuit design in there (e.g. safely executing a circuit with 2-3 hot phases and a shared neutral), but mostly it's all about manner of execution of work.  Insulation types, wire ampacity, how they are physically protected, how safety grounding/earthing is done, how neutrals are protected from overload even though they're not fused... there is literally a chapter on each topic.

So, your locality will have an Electrical Code, and it will call out specific methods which are approved for wire splicing.  You have to use one of those.

ThreePhaseEel has an excellent answer. In Europe they are also fond of miniature lug connections (place wire into a hole, tighten screw to clamp).   Here in America you'd use "wire nuts" typically, which are proven when done competently - I advise a "pull test" to affirm proper construction.

Answer (score 1):

Solder is a good thing because protects from oxidation of surface, and you c eve reach low contact resistance, but it is not accepted by electrical safety standards. A inspectable terminal junction that gives a repeatable and guaranteed electrical contact should be used instead.
If you are not a clever electrician, your soldered joint will be poor quality, maybe will crack. Two copper wires held in place by a screw with pressure applied by a shaped surface is repeatable and achieves a satisfactory contact resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Soldering won't really help, is easy to do wrong, is hard to service later, and may not be legal in your country.

If installed properly I've never seen a 10¢ [twist on wire connector](https://www.idealind.com/content/dam/electrical/assets/WireTermination/WireConnectors/TwistOn/WireNut/WireNut%20WireConnector%20Instructions.pdf) fail, but if you really want to enter overkill category you could use a $10 insulated set screw connector. Given the choice I sleep best using a 10¢ connector in my own home.

But solder? You have to make a good mechanical connection, heat the wire to solder melting point without damaging insulation, then wrap will appropriate insulating tape. If you ever need to disconnect you need to cut it out and start over.

But relative to the size wire codes require I wouldn't even consider 5kw as "high power consumption". For instance the minimum building wire size allowed in the US is rated by testing labs at 25A (#14 THHN), which is more than your water heater would draw at 220V. Then to compensate for possible heat then NEC then requires upgrading the wire two sizes to wire rated for 40A. The expansion issues caused by heat are effectively none at that level.

Comment: Although technically legal by NEC 110.14 you may experience excessive scrutiny form  an inspector that may suspect you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that your electrical code may not allow you to bury a splice, meaning a splice has to be in a box and the box must remain accessible.  The way you're talking about extending a wire, you should be aware of this.  The exception I can think of is that for underground runs you can get splice kits meant for direct burial.

Answer (score -2):

5kW represents quite a lot of amps.  Just twisting wires together isn't adequate.  Over time, the copper will oxidise, and the joint will deteriorate.

Soldering, then properly insulating, the joint would work.

Alternatively, use terminal blocks or compression terminals (such as Wago blocks).

Comment: All the other answers are missing the point. Trouble with yours is that is shows no sources nor calculations. How much is twisted+soldered joint better electrically than just twisted one? THAT is the question.

Answer (score -4):

I think you can joint but wound wire around the joint. Public Electric Grid people do so. Their current is high. To compensiate conductivity the diameter at joint should be larger. This is my openion because we have seen responsible electric supplyers do so.[image]

Comment: This answer is not very clear, could you elaborate? What do you mean with “I think you can joint but wound wire around the joint”? Also, the fact you’ve seen responsible persons doing this does not mean it is the right solulution in this particular situation.

Comment: I also think joints are no good. But he says the cable is long and he does not like to throw it away and replace a new one.